# Can someone explain to me why there are 2 inclusions of jQuery in the EmberJS Starter kit

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've just been looking at the index.html that comes with the EmberJS starter kit that you get by clicking "Download Starter Kit" on http://emberjs.com/

There is a bit of a strange bit of the code at the end of the body tag (loading scripts at the last moment):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-0.9.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Ok I understand the last two,  load the ember library and then run the ember app. I also understand the first one, get the jQuery from Google's CDN but I don't understand why you would ever have the second script tag! Is this just so that you don't depend on Google's CDN and ship your own copy of jQuery?

Can someone tell me if this is best practice or if I should be filing a bug with EmberJS so that they remove this from their starter kit.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the author is thinking that in case jquery is unable to load from the googleapis then to be safe include a local version. Notice the

```
!window.jQuery
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I worked out from the code but I think the bit that I was missing was the reason **why** it needed to have a fallback. I got an answer on twitter that Pointed me to [this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/cdn-hosted-jquery-with-fallback-local-copy/) that explains it like this:
**Why bother falling back to a local copy?**
There may be times when the CDN version cannot be loaded. 
For example:
 - you're doing development on a disconnected computer
 - a country or workplace network blocks the CDN
 - various connectivity issues

Answer (score 3):

If jQuery is loaded from the first script tag, then `window.jQuery` would evaluate to true.  Thus, `!window.jQuery` would evaluate to false, and the expression in the second line would short circuit.  However, if jQuery did not load from the first line, then `!window.jQuery` will be true, and the document will write the script tag for a privately hosted version.  This allows the client to load jQuery from Google APIs, which will probably be faster, but gives them a fallback in case the load fails.

You might want to read up on [type coercion](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html) in JavaScript.